# Reducing the spacing of specific cells in a collectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I show several cells in a collectionview, some of those cells are paired (stereo audio channels) and i want them to be merged together as seemingly 1 button, rather than having the generic collectionview padding other cells have.

Is there a way I can remove the padding between 2 specific cells to merge into 1 larger cell? Perhaps removing the right hand padding of the first cell in the pair? Or is this beyond the scope of the collectionview?

Here is my delegate method:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CDCBusSelectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *busNameString = [self.busNamesRecieved objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.busNameCell.text = busNameString;

    NSNumber *busStereoState = [self.busStereoStateRecieved objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger busIntState = [busStereoState integerValue];
    if (busIntState == 1) {
        // stereo -- need to merge cells or something
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:90 blue:127 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Design your cells with "padding"... Set cell-spacing to Zero... adjust the padding of your adjacent cells that you want to look like 1.

Comment: is cell spacing a delegate method of its own? how would you specify specific cells?

Comment: This is the idea: https://imgur.com/a/9lt9K  ... Zero spacing between cells... each cell has a red subview with 4-pt inset on each side... cells 2, 6 and 10 change the Trailing padding to Zero, and cells 3, 7 and 11 change the Leading padding to Zero, making it look like the "paired" cells are individual, wider cells.

Comment: sorry for the delay on this, i have set the spacing to zero, whats the property to add padding to cells specifically?